# What is the purpose to create Application and Loader in Lagom

Tags: lagom

I am reading following tutorial on Lagom.

I understand DI but the section also talks of Application and Loader. I am unable to understand the purpose of creating an Application and Loader class. So far, I have been able to run basic services (e.g., hello, world service from [GettingStarted](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/scala/IntroGetStarted.html)) without creating Application and loader class.

Comment: It is used for mixing in important traits. Consider i18n or CORS.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider a sample ApplicationLoader (and this is not the only way to do but an example for the sake of the question)

```
abstract class FriendModule (context: LagomApplicationContext)
  extends LagomApplication(context)
    with AhcWSComponents
    with CassandraPersistenceComponents
{

  persistentEntityRegistry.register(wire[FriendEntity])    
  override def jsonSerializerRegistry = FriendSerializerRegistry

  override lazy val lagomServer: LagomServer = serverFor[FriendService](wire[FriendServiceImpl])
}

class FriendApplicationLoader extends LagomApplicationLoader {

  override def load(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication =
    new FriendModule(context) with ConductRApplicationComponents

  override def loadDevMode(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication =
    new FriendModule(context) with LagomDevModeComponents

  override def describeService = Some(readDescriptor[FriendService])
}
```

Firstly the reason we create a class `FriendModule` that extends `LagomApplication, is to mixin all our dependencies. They could be:

- If the application relies on cassandra and persistence api, then we mixin that. If the application needs to make HTTP calls then we provide it the WSClient etc
- We of-course wire in the compile time dependencies
- By doing below, we bind the implementation with the service declared

  override lazy val lagomServer: LagomServer = serverForFriendService

But notice, we haven't still coupled our microservice with a **Service Locator**.

The role of a service locator is to provide the ability to discover application services and communicate with them. For example: If an application has five different microservices running, then each one would need to know the address of every other for the communication to be possible.
Service Locator takes this responsibility of keeping information of the address of the microservices concerned. In the absence of this service locator, we would need to configure the URL of each microservice and make it available to each microservice (may be via a properties file?).

So in the class `FriendApplicationLoader` we bind our implementation with `LagomDevModeComponents` in the dev case. `LagomDevModeComponents`registers our service with the registry. This is how magically Lagom microservices can communicate with others in a simple manner.

Comment: In your snippet you're mixing `LagomDevModeComponents` into `load`. Shouldn't int go into `loadDevMode` instead? (and vice-versa for the `ConductRApplicationComponents` trait).